# why images are not showing on an electron built version

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

this is the electron code, built with React.js and electron. if I start the electron app the images show up but if I start the built(electron-built) version of the app the images do not show up. Any hint?

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen: electronScreen, protocol } = require('electron');
.......

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createMainWindow();

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (!BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length) {
      createMainWindow();
    }
  });
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) =>{
    const pathname = decodeURI(request.url.replace('file:///', ''))
    callback(pathname)
  })
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
})
```